# A bug ? Property in an extension of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, swift-extensions

I created an extension for the `UIView`:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    var frameHeight : CGFloat {

        get {
            return self.frame.size.height
        }
        set(newHeight) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y,self.frame.size.width, newHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I used this inside the method of my own `UIView`:

```
class MyView: UIView {

   func updateHeight() {

        self.frameHeight = 200.0
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

I got a compile error:

```
While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC15Simple15MyView10updateHeightfS0_FT_T_ for 'updateHeight' at /MyView.swift:88:5
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

When I comment out the line `self.frameHeight = 200.0`, the compile error is gone.

Is it a bug? Or did I do something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try a full clean (command-shift-option-K) and then compile again.

Comment: Did several times. Doesn't help at all.

Comment: A there any workaround? Or the only way is to wait for Apple to fix the bug ?

Comment: Try explicitly casting 200.0 to CGFloat (`CGFloat(200.0)`).

Comment: Tried something like that. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I run it in a Playground and I don't see anything obviously wrong.

In any case, even if it *is* a bug in your code, it shouldn't crash the compiler. I think you should [create a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with Apple.

Comment: When I run this in Playground (actually not run but only input to the playground, the Xcode crashes.

Comment: You should definitely raise a bug then. It's difficult to suggest a workaround if its behaviour varies depending on the environment.

Comment: Yes. I'll do that. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: I did another test by using UIKit in playground. Yes, it works in playground but not in my project code.

Comment: The funny thing is I reported to Apple and it's gone now. But the problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your `func` as `mutating`.